# Python exec() when called in class breaks on lambda

Tags: python, lambda, exec, code-generation

I'm doing code generation and I end up with a string of source that looks like this:

**Source**

```
import sys
import operator

def add(a,b):
    return operator.add(a,b)

def mul(a,b):
    return operator.mul(a,b)

def saveDiv(a,b):
    if b==0:
        return 0
    else:
        return a/b

def subtract(a,b):
    return operator.sub(a,b)

def main(y,x,z):
   y = int(y)
    print y
    x = int(x)
    print x
    z = int(z)
    print z
    ind = lambda y,x,z: mul(saveDiv(x, add(z, z)), 1)
    return ind(y,x,z)

print main(**sys.argv)""
```

**Execution**

When I'm executing code using `exec()` and then piping it through `stdoutIO()`

**Working**

```
args={'x':"1",'y':"1",'z':"1"}
source = getSource()
sys.argv = args
with stdoutIO() as s:
    exec source
s.getvalue
```

**Not Working**

```
class Coder():

    def start(self):

        args={'x':"1",'y':"1",'z':"1"}

        source = getSource()
        sys.argv = args

        with stdoutIO() as s:
            exec source

        return s.getvalue

print "out:", Coder().start()
```

And the `stdoutIO()` is implemented like this:

```
class Proxy(object):

    def __init__(self,stdout,stringio):
        self._stdout = stdout
        self._stringio = stringio

    def __getattr__(self,name):
        if name in ('_stdout','_stringio','write'):
            object.__getattribute__(self,name)
        else:
            return getattr(self._stringio,name)

    def write(self,data):
         self._stdout.write(data)
         self._stringio.write(data)

    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def stdoutIO(stdout=None):
        old = sys.stdout
        if stdout is None:
            stdout = StringIO.StringIO()
        sys.stdout = Proxy(sys.stdout,stdout)
        yield sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = old
```

**Problem**

If I execute the execution code outside of the class everything works however when I run it inside a class it breaks with this error. How can I fix it or avoid this problem?

```
  File "<string>", line 29, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 27, in main
  File "<string>", line 26, in <lambda>
  NameError: global name 'add' is not defined
```

Thanks

Comment: How did you execute it outside the class?

Comment: If I run exec(source) inside a class any class it breaks. However if I run it outside (not sure how the environment is called ) as it is showed in my example it works fine.

Comment: Could you post a (non-)working example so we can reproduce your failure?

Comment: @GeorgeKouzmov So the problem is with you using a context manager?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I've edited the post.

Problem is when I'm using the exec() inside a class the lambda function breaks and can't find the functions given to it in the source. It works perfectly if ran normally as shown in the example.

Comment: I'm asking for a single blob of source code.

Comment: What's `getSource`, and what are you `exec`uting?

Comment: Why the heck are you assigning a dict to `sys.argv`? `sys.argv` is a list of program arguments; assigning a dict there makes no sense.

Comment: Why are you using ``exec`` anyway? What you have presented seems overly complex for what it's "meant to do".

Comment: @StevenRumbalski In my post **Source** is the source code I'm testing it with. Get source is what is retrieving it. sys.argv when given a dict works as x=1 y=1 z=1 so the arguments can be mapped.

Comment: @James Mills I'm doing genetic programming and this is converting my individuals to source at times I'm working with millions of them so writing them to a file and executing it is not a good idea. This is the simplest way I've found so far. If you have better suggestions I'd love to test them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `exec expression`, it executes the code contained in `expression` in the current scope (see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec)). Apparently inside a class, the function in your expression are dropping out of scope before `main` is run. I honestly have no idea why (it seems to me like it should work) but maybe someone can add a complete explanation in a comment.

Anyway, if you specifically provide a scope for the expression to be evaluated in, (which is good practice anyway so that you don't pollute your namespace), it works fine inside the class.

So, replace the line:

```
    exec source
```

with

```
    exec source in {}
```

and you should be right!

Here we provide an empty dictionary as a the globals() and locals() dctionaries during the evaluation of your expression. You can keep this dictionary if you want, or let it be garbage collected immediately as I have demonstrated in my code. This is all explained in the exec documentation in the link above.

Comment: @GeorgeKouzmov You're welcome. I should add that if you keep the dictionary around, you will have access to the functions defined in the expression. For instance you could call, after `exec source in mydict`, `print mydict['add'](1,2)`. Not sure if that is any use to you, but thought I would mention it!